# Can't Connect Sql Server To the DataBase make Network Related Error

Tags: sql-server

When I try to connect SQL Server it gives error like

> A network-related or instance-specific error occured while
>   establishing a connection to sql sever.The server was not found or was
>   not accessible.verify that the instance name is correct and that Sql
>   Server is configured o allow remote connections.(provider:Shared
>   Memory Provider,error:40-Could not open a connection to Sql Server(
>   (Microsoft Sql Server ,Error:2).

Last day it work fine but next day I got the error like this.

Also in SQL Server Configuration Manager, SQL Server Service stopped. When I try to start it make error like

> The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely
>   fashion.Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for
>   details.

So what is the error?

Comment: There's some error happening when trying to start SQL Server instance. Check Event Viewer (eventvwr) and see what's the specific error upon startup.

Answer (score 0):

Check you SQL Server instance to make sure it's configured to allow remote connections. It's a setting you can control in SQL Server management studio.

This link explains how
http://forums.asp.net/t/1338911.aspx/1